# Cannot create an instance of class ViewModel Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class .ViewModel has no zero argument constructor

Tags: android, android-fragments, viewmodel

Here is my ViewModel class

```
import android.content.Context
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel

 class ViewModel (private val context: Context) : ViewModel() {

    private var leadslist = MutableLiveData<Response>()

 init {
        val Repository: Repository by lazy {
            Repository
        }
            leadslist = Repository.getMutableLiveData(context)

    }

    fun getLeadsList(): MutableLiveData<Response> {
        return leadslist

    }
}
```

Here is how I am calling it in my Fragment.

```
viewmodel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(ViewModel::class.java)
```

I know there are other answers already but nothing seems to work. Please help. Stuck on this for a pretty long time.

I have tried ViewModelFactory too.

```
ViewModelProvider(requireActivity(),ViewModelFactory(requireActivity())).get(ViewModel::class.java)
```

and used this code for ViewModelFactory class

```
import android.content.Context
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider

 class ViewModelFactory(private val context: Context) : ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory() {

    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return ViewModel(context) as T
    }

}
```

still, it doesn't work.

Then I tried this

```
viewmodel= ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory(requireActivity().application)
      .create(ViewModel::class.java)
```

and it didn't work again.

And how do create this zero-argument constructor in my ViewModel.
And why can't I create instance.

Also, with one of the approach I was able to compile and run but in that the viewmodel.observe function wasn't executing.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Have your class extend `AndroidViewModel` -- at that point, you should no longer need a custom factory. I also recommend naming it something other than `ViewModel`.

Comment: Just tried it. It runs without errors. But it doesn't execute ViewModel.observe , so I am not able to add values to my adapter due to that.

Comment: I do not know what "it" is in "it doesn't execute". You can see examples of `AndroidViewModel` in use [here](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-kotlin/-/blob/v2.0/DiceLight/src/main/java/com/commonsware/jetpack/diceware/MainMotor.kt), [here](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-kotlin/-/blob/v2.0/ContentEditor/src/main/java/com/commonsware/jetpack/contenteditor/MainMotor.kt), and [here](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-kotlin/-/blob/v2.0/Bookmarker/src/main/java/com/commonsware/jetpack/bookmarker/MainMotor.kt).

Answer (score 1):

The parameter `context` must be initialized.

like:

```
class ViewModel (private val context: Context = requireActivity().application) : ViewModel()
```